# Optimizing algorithm

Tags: python

i've gotten an exercise in regards to one of the classes that i'm taking at Uni. My problem is not that i can't solve the problem but that my algorithm isn't fast enough.

## The assignment

Josefine has spent the entire summer deciding what courses she wants to study at The University of Algorithms. A course takes one semester to finish (and as the super student she is, she always succeeds). Some of the courses depends on other courses, and it is therefore not allowed to take these in the same semester. If course i depends on course j, Josefine must take course i in an earlier semester than course j. She wants to finish her studies in as few semesters as possible.

Given the N courses Josefine wants to study (numbered from 1 to N), and the courses they each depend on, compute the fewest number of semesters Josefine needs to use to finish her studies. (Again, she is a super student, so she can take an unlimited number of courses each semester).

You can assume there is no cyclic dependencies in the courses Josefine has chosen.

Input format

```
Line 1: The integers N and M, where N is the number of courses and M is the total number of dependencies.
Line 2..M+1: Two integers X and Y meaning the course X depends on the course Y (ie. course Y must have been completed before course X)
```

Output format

```
Line 1: The fewest number of semesters Josefine needs to use.
```

## My current code

```
NM = input()
NM = NM.split(" ")
N = int(NM[0])
M = int(NM[1])

remCourses = []
courseRes = {}
for i in range(1,N+1):
    courseRes[str(i)] = list()
    remCourses.append(str(i))

for i in range(0,M):
    res = input()
    res = res.split(" ")
    courseRes[str(res[0])].append(str(res[1]))

semCount = 0
while len(remCourses) > 0:
    newCourses = []
    for key in courseRes:
        if len(courseRes[key]) == 0:
            newCourses.append(key)


    for l in range(1,N+1):
        for course in newCourses:
            if course in courseRes[str(l)]:
                courseRes[str(l)].remove(course)

    for course in newCourses:
        if course in remCourses:
            remCourses.remove(course)

    semCount += 1

print(semCount)
```

My problem is that the code isn't fast enough to get the points needed. Would really appreciate som help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Who defines how fast it is? How do you test it?

Comment: This question may be better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You need to spend the longest chain of dependencies or 1 if no dependencies present in semesters.

Comment: You haven't done any of the regular things to make things faster (put code in a function, use sets and dicts when you're doing `in` testing, don't repeat yourself in nested loops, use idiomatic code -- e.g. `if not x:` instead of `if len(x) == 0:`)...

Comment: For what Python version did you write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the solution much faster by using set operations.

First assume we have the following dependencies:

```
deps = [(11, 2), (11, 9), (8, 9), (11, 10), (3, 10),
        (5, 11), (7, 11), (7, 8), (3, 8)]
```

which forms the following graph:

[image: wikipedia dag]

to find the courses she would need to take during the first semester:

```
semesters = []
sources = {start for start, end in deps}
sinks   = {end for start, end in deps}
semester = sources - sinks
semesters.append(semester)
```

i.e. find all the roots in the graph (nodes without any incoming arrows).

Then remove the roots:

```
deps = [(start, end) for start, end in deps if start not in semester]
```

and repeat...

```
semesters = []
while deps:
    sources = {start for start, end in deps}
    sinks   = {end for start, end in deps}
    semester = sources - sinks
    semesters.append(semester)
    deps = [(start, end) for start, end in deps if start not in semester]

print("semesters needed:", 1 + len(semesters))
```

we need to add 1 since the last removal of roots removes 2 levels of nodes.

We can compare the two versions using the `timeit` module (I've put your code in a function and fixed a couple of bugs):

```
def semestercount():
    deps = [(11, 2), (11, 9), (8, 9), (11, 10), (3, 10),
            (5, 11), (7, 11), (7, 8), (3, 8)]
    count = 0
    while deps:
        sources = {start for start, end in deps}
        sinks   = {end for start, end in deps}
        semester = sources - sinks
        count += 1
        deps = [(start, end) for start, end in deps if start not in semester]
    return count + 1


def op_code():
    NM = [(11, 2), (11, 9), (8, 9), (11, 10), (3, 10),
          (5, 11), (7, 11), (7, 8), (3, 8)]
    nodes = list(set(sum(NM, ())))
    N = len(nodes)
    M = len(NM)
    remCourses = []
    courseRes = {}
    for i in range(N):
        courseRes[nodes[i]] = list()
        remCourses.append(nodes[i])

    for i in range(0,M):
        res = NM[i]
        courseRes[res[0]].append(res[1])

    semCount = 0
    while len(remCourses) > 0:
        newCourses = []
        for key in courseRes:
            if len(courseRes[key]) == 0:
                newCourses.append(key)


        for l in range(N):
            for course in newCourses:
                if course in courseRes[nodes[l]]:
                    courseRes[nodes[l]].remove(course)

        for course in newCourses:
            if course in remCourses:
                remCourses.remove(course)

        semCount += 1
    return semCount


import timeit
print timeit.timeit("semestercount()", "from __main__ import semestercount")
print timeit.timeit("op_code()", "from __main__ import op_code")
```

on my computer it prints:

```
5.85758427398
42.8849096743
```

so quite a bit faster :-)